# Mapping MVC routes with meaningful names to each method for Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes, web

The standard route for the MVC Web API is {controller}/{id}. However I'd like to name my variables more descriptively then just 'id'. To do this though it would make more sense to me if I could map routes directly to methods as the WCF Web API worked. Is there a way to do this with MVC or is there is a more MVCish way of routing but still maintaining unique identifiable placeholders for each method?. Or am I stuck just naming all my parameters id?

```
    [WebGet(UriTempalte="{controller}/{email}"]
    public string GetEmail(string email)
```

Instead of:

```
    public string GetEmail(string id)
```

Comment: I assume you're using asp.net-mvc. How routing works differers between frameworks.

Comment: Yes, it is ASP.NET MVC 4. It's replacing the WCF Web API so I'm trying to adjust to the new framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you name it `email` - then create a separate Route in Global.asax.cs naming your parameter accordingly, i.e. `{controller}\{email}`. In MVC routes you only have a very short list of MVC-specific keywords - {controller}, {action}, {area} etc. All the other parameters are passed to corresponding action parameters (if they are present in your action method signature of course).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `routes.MapRoute("getemail/{email}", new { controller = "EmailGetter", action = "GetEmail" })` suffice you?